# Autocomplete Jquery, and show results

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

how i can create a search, with an autocomplete from json file, and after submit value show resultes in new page with data of value selected

here is the html file:

```
<form action="/dosomething">
<input/>
<button type="submit"></button>
</form>
```

my json file :

```
    [
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite1",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite2",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow2.com"
        },
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite3",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow3.com"
        }
   ]
```

how i can parse data for autocomplete and showing results after do that's ?
help please, and thank !

Comment: jQuery actually has an autocomplete object in it's UI library. I would recommend checking out the examples as they have the full code: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 0):

Form will submit to whatever action you have it directed to.  So simply call the autocomplete on the field you want to fill, define the data, and you should be off to the races.

```
<form action="/dosomething">
    <input id="fillme" />
    <button type="submit"></button>
</form>



var sourceJSON =  [
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite1",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite2",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow2.com"
        },
        {
           "title": "Stackoverflowsite3",
           "link": "www.stackoverflow3.com"
        }
   ]

$( "#fillme" ).autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: sourceJSON,
      focus: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#fillme" ).val( ui.item.title );
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#fillme" ).val( ui.item.title );

        return false;
      }
    }).autocomplete( "instance" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
  return $( "<li>" )
    .append( "<a>" + item.title+ "</a>" )
    .appendTo( ul );
};
```

Comment: Thnx but not working for me, a demo on jsfiddle would be awesome :) !